# View Animation is not working more than once

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewanimation

I want to start an animation after completing an animation for that i implemented the following code in touchesBegan function

```
if(touch.view==word1)
{


    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                         word1.alpha=1;                    


                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if (finished) {
                             word1.alpha=0;
                         }
                     }];


}
```

It is working for the first touch, when i touch it again it is not working at all. Can anyone please tell me what wrong have i done.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't understand. Do you want to start the animation when you touch it again or when the other animation is finished? If you want to fade out you have to repeat the entire animation block.... setting word1.alpha = 0 does not animate it...

Comment: Ron is correct. You will have to do another animation inside the completion block.

Comment: @Ron I want to start the same animation when i touch it again.

Comment: Check the answers below.. That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

A view who's alpha is on 0 (which it is after the animation)
doesn't respond to userinteraction and passes those events on to the underlying view ;)

Comment: So what shall i do for solving this issue.

Comment: I think that is the case only if the setHidden property is set to true. For alpha = 0, it's just invisible but present and will respond to user interaction.

Comment: Nope, alpha = 0 views are ignored aswell. iOS internally calls the function hitTest:withEvent: to find out which view should handle the touch event. Here's a small excerpt from the documentation ;) "This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interactions, or have an alpha level less than 0.01."

Comment: So to solve the issue we would first need to know why you are hiding a view on touch... Showing it again with a 2nd touch isn't very intuitive to a user... a way around it would be to set the backgroundcolor to [UIColor clearColor] instead

Answer (score 0):

When you set alpha to 0, also set userinteraction set to FALSE

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing an image, you could make your image a subview of a UIView, and like Infinite said you could set the background color to clearColor, and use the UIView for the touch event.